# Where does the polarity of particles come from?

Tags: particle-physics

Going though current lessons, I can clearly see that some particles, electrons, are charged negatively and other, protons, are charged positively.
Where does this polarity come from? Knowing that negative and positive particles exist, why would they attract each other?

Thank you.

Comment: *"Knowing that negative and positive particles exist, why would they attract each other? "* How do you know they're positively/negatively charged if not by the fact how they repel/attract each other?

Comment: There are really several different questions here. (1) Why does electric charge come in two flavors rather than one (like mass) or three (like color charge)? (2) Why do like charges repel and unlike charges attract, instead of the other way around? (3) Why is it convenient to represent the two types of charges with positive and negative numbers?

Comment: I agree with Ben. Chirac: Which of these questions would you rather ask about? You can put the other non-duplicates in a separate question.